# Is there a way to extract the camera feed w.r.t the imageTargeted being tracked?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm trying to implement an app that involves sending the recognized imagetrack to a server for further process. I want to extract from the camera feed only the part of my imageTarget.

The current way I'm doing it is by first find the position of the target (which is a square), roughly find its four corners, and then convert from world space to screen space to get the minX/Y, maxX/Y values to resample from the whole camera input.

Code:

```
var image = VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.CameraDevice.GetCameraImage(PIXEL_FORMAT);


var targetPos = target.transform.position;
var size = target.GetSize();
var sx = target.transform.right * size.x * 0.5f;
var sz = target.transform.forward * size.y * 0.5f;
var bottomLeft = targetPos - sx - sz;
var topLeft = targetPos - sx + sz;
var topRight = targetPos + sx + sz;
var bottomRight = targetPos + sx - sz;

var topLeftScreen = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(bottomLeft);
var topRightScreen = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(bottomRight);
var bottomLeftScreen = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(topLeft);
var bottomRightScreen = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(topRight);
// also okay to use screenpoint, but not good for in-unity-editor debugging

var minX = Mathf.Max(Mathf.FloorToInt(Mathf.Min(topLeftScreen.x, topRightScreen.x, bottomLeftScreen.x, bottomRightScreen.x) * image.Width) - 10, 0);
var maxX = Mathf.Min(Mathf.CeilToInt(Mathf.Max(topLeftScreen.x, topRightScreen.x, bottomLeftScreen.x, bottomRightScreen.x) * image.Width) + 10, image.Width);
var minY = Mathf.Max(Mathf.FloorToInt(Mathf.Min(topLeftScreen.y, topRightScreen.y, bottomLeftScreen.y, bottomRightScreen.y) * image.Height) - 10, 0);
var maxY = Mathf.Min(Mathf.CeilToInt(Mathf.Max(topLeftScreen.y, topRightScreen.y, bottomLeftScreen.y, bottomRightScreen.y) * image.Height) + 10, image.Height);

newImage = new byte[(maxX - minX) * (maxY - minY)];
for (var y = minY; y < maxY; y++) {
    for (var x = minX; x < maxX; x++) {
        newImage[(int)((y - minY) * (maxX - minX) + (x - minX))] = image.Pixels[y * image.Width + x];
    }
}
```

However the coordinates I get is not close to the optimal points and thus the cropped image is bad. Is there any way for me to improve it, or would it be possible to directly acquire it through Vuforia API?

Comment: Could you add an image to show how the coordinates deviate from the optimum?